# Understanding Java Sorting a 2D-Array using Arrays.sort()

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was working on a Leetcode problem(452. Minimum Number of Arrows to Burst Balloon). I came across a user sorting their 2D-array as:

```
Arrays.sort(points, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]));
```

I am still trying to get used to using Java and it's not clear to me the logic behind using the `Integer.compare(a[1], b[1])`.

How does this define how it's being sorted? Would really appreciate an explanation and perspective on why using this approach to sort the 2D-array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[1], b[1])` is a lambda expression and in this case is an implementation of [`Comparator#compare(T,T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)). That method determines whether the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second argument by returning a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer, respectively. The `Integer.compare(int,int)` method works the same way, just only with `int` arguments.

The sorting algorithm used by `Arrays#sort(...)` iterates over the array and compares its elements using the `Comparator`. The algorithm will consult the `Comparator` as many times as needed, using the results of the comparisons to determine which elements need to be moved, until the array is sorted.

A 2D array is essentially just an array of arrays. So what's happening is the "outer" array is being sorted based on the values at index `1` of the "inner" arrays.

---

If you're still unsure about the lambda expression it's equivalent to the following:

```java
Arrays.sort(points, new Comparator<int[]>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int a1 = a[1];
    int b1 = b[1];

    // Integer.compare(a1, b1)
    if (a1 < b1) {
      return -1; // negative = less than
    } else if (a1 == b1) {
      return 0; // zero = equal to
    } else {
      return 1; // positive = greater than
    }
  }
});
```

Assuming `points` is an `int[][]`.

Comment: Got it! This makes a lot of sense! Thank you! Also will this be always be the case where you need to use some comparator when sorting a 2D-Array using Arrays.sort()?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. If it helps think of lists. The above is like sorting a `List<int[]>`. If you have a `double[][]` it's like sorting a `List<double[]>`. If you have a `String[][]` it's like sorting a `List<String[]>`. However, if you have a `String[]` it's like sorting a `List<String>`.

Comment: Oh wow that's a good way of thinking about that! That was very helpful! Thank you!